# DIV keeps returning back to the same position when animation stop playing?

Tags: html, css, animation

The Div reappeared after the animation stops playing, how do you stop the div from returning to the original place?

```
    #wrapper {
    background-color: #999;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#wrapper .section{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 51%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #222222;
}
#wrapper .section.section-left{
    left:0;
    animation: move 1.5s 1;

}
#wrapper .section.section-right{
    right:0;
    animation: move 1.5s 1;

}
@keyframes move{
     0%   {width: 51%;}
    100% {width:0%;}
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="section section-left"></div>
<div class="section section-right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You can add, `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` to `#wrapper .section.section-left` and `#wrapper .section.section-right`

[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/o0nico0o/pen/YqQBNG)